# How is collision avoidance regulated in controlled airspace in Canada?

Tags: air-traffic-control, transport-canada

According to CAR [302.31(3)](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-96-433/FullText.html#s-602.31ss-(3)ID0EDDA) "Compliance with Air Traffic Control Instructions and Clearances"

> The pilot-in-command of an aircraft may deviate from an air traffic control clearance or an air traffic control instruction to the extent necessary to carry out a collision avoidance manoeuvre, if the manoeuvre is carried out
>
> > (a) in accordance with a resolution advisory generated by an **ACAS**; or
> >
> > (b) in response to an alert from a **TAWS** or a Ground Proximity Warning System (**GPWS**).

I know that even in controlled airspace with separation/conflict resolution, and without equipment mentioned in (a) and (b) it is the responsibility of the pilot to avoid collisions. Is that covered by a different CAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, it applies when operating in the vicinity of an aerodrome:

> #### Division V — Operations at or in the Vicinity of an Aerodrome
>
> 602.96 (1) This section applies to persons operating VFR or IFR aircraft at or in the vicinity of an uncontrolled or controlled aerodrome.
>
> (3) The pilot-in-command of an aircraft operating at or in the vicinity of an aerodrome shall
>
> > (a) observe aerodrome traffic for the purpose of avoiding a collision;

Also this part:

> #### Part VI — General Operating and Flight Rules
>
> 602.19 (1) Notwithstanding any other provision of this section,
>
> > (a) the pilot-in-command of an aircraft that has the right of way shall, if there is any risk of collision, take such action as is necessary to avoid collision; and
> >
> > (b) where the pilot-in-command of an aircraft is aware that another aircraft is in an emergency situation, the pilot-in-command shall give way to that other aircraft.

The way I'd interpret the above is vigilance in see-and-avoid is always there, unless of course you don't have ACAS and TAWS and flying IFR in instrument meteorological conditions (IMC).

Comment: Does that mean though that when not in the vicinity of an aerodrome I must not "deviate from an air traffic control clearance or an air traffic control instruction to the extent necessary to carry out a collision avoidance manoeuvre" unless (a) or (b) above are met?

Comment: @Tobias added new section

Comment: That makes perfect sense, how did I not see that! Thanks for digging.